# How can client get resource claims about the user in IdentityServer4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

My client get token from `IdentityServer4` and give it to my `API` to get service,
all thing goes true until i want  to get user claim (which STS automatically put on the user claim), when i call `User.Identity.Name`, it return null. 
Accroding to the [This Link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3644) i should define Scope in the API startup, so i define:

```
  app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:33934",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ApiName = "api1",
            AllowedScopes = { "profile", "email", "api1" },
        });
```

All thing goes right, my user can get Token from IdentityServer, and when i pass it to API, the `Authorization` will done successfully, but the `User.Identity.Name`  return null!
what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can print out the list of claims using

```
<dl>
    @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
    {
        <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
        <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
    }
</dl>
```

Try this on the client app and you will know if you are getting value in name or not.